# Exception happen on get session from EntityManager after commit and close before session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Get instance for EntityManager by below annotation config in Dao class. Used Dao class in a Rest API as bellow. when call save dao method first time, new UserEntity('name-1', 'password-1') save in database, but when call second save method(userDao.save(new UserEntity('name-2', 'password-2'))), happend exception by message "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed".

```
public class REST {
    @Autowire
    DaoUser userDao;

    public void save(){
         userDao.save(new UserEntity('name-1', 'password-1'));
         userDao.save(new UserEntity('name-2', 'password-2'));
    }
}

 class UserDao {
      @PersistenceContext(
        name = "stadto",
        type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION
       )
      private EntityManager manager;

      public void save(UserEntity user){
         Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
         Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
         transaction.beginTransaction();
         session.save(user);
         transaction.commit();
         session.close();
      }
 }
```

Comment: 1. Stop using the proprietary hibernate API/ You can persist entity using the EntityManager directly. 2. Spring has support for declarative transaction management. Use it. Read the documentation. Don't begin and commit transactions yourself, ever.  3. Spring-data-jpa allows having ready-to-use DAOs. You don't need to implement a save method yourself.

Comment: Regarding the exception, it's quite simple: you close the session, so... the session is closed. Don't, ever, close the session. Don't even use the session at all. Use the EntityManager, and let Spring open and close it for you.

Comment: I know that can use entitymanager for persist data in database, but I want use session.

Comment: I really don't understand why you choose to use a non-standard API. Even Hibernate recommends using the standard JPA API. And you're thus also losing the support from spring-data-jpa. But anyway, even if you choose to use the hibernate API, read the Spring user guide, and do it as explained there. Don't manage transactions and sessions yourself. And at least be coherent: if you choose not to use JPA, then don't use JPA.

Comment: I expected when get session from entitymanager, session is new per call. Why session is not new per call  entitymanager.unwrap(session.class) ?

Comment: Because the persistence context is bound to the current transaction, handled by Spring.

Comment: If do not close session after commit, session when will be close?

Comment: Yes. Spring handles that for you. It also opens and commits and rollbacks transactions for you. If you use spring-data-jpa, it also generates queries for you. By not reading the documentation, you're making your life much more difficult than it should be.

Comment: I used entitymanager and transactional annotation, but it is not dynamic for me. It has some constraint such as flush between two transactional method that they related to each other, or rollback manually handle in code, so  I can not use that.

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. Learn how it works and how it's supposed to be used.